# Python-pandas Replace NA with the median or mean of a group in dataframe

Tags: python, r, dataframe

Suppose we have a df:

```
    A       B
   apple   1.0
   apple   2.0
   apple    NA
   orange   NA
   orange  7.0
   melon   14.0
   melon   NA
   melon   15.0
   melon   16.0
```

to replace the NA, we can use `df["B"].fillna(df["B"].median())`, but it will fill NA with the median of all data in "B"

Is there any way that we can use the median of a certain A to replace the NA (like below):

```
    A       B
   apple   1.0
   apple   2.0
   apple   **1.5**
   orange  **7.0**
   orange  7.0
   melon   14.0
   melon   **15.0**
   melon   15.0
   melon   16.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: `with(dd, ifelse(is.na(B), ave(B, A, FUN = function(x) median(x, na.rm = TRUE)), B))`

Comment: This shld not have an R tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In pandas you may use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) to obtain null-fill values:

```
>>> med = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('median')
>>> df['B'].fillna(med)
0     1.0
1     2.0
2     1.5
3     7.0
4     7.0
5    14.0
6    15.0
7    15.0
8    16.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Can you do that for all columns simultaneously and avoid having to specify the columns? In R for example this could be done as df <- na.roughfix(df)

Answer (score 2):

In `R`,  can use `na.aggregate/data.table` to replace the `NA` by `mean` value of the group.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'A', apply the `na.aggregate` on 'B'.

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  B:= na.aggregate(B), A]
df
#      A    B
#1:  apple  1.0
#2:  apple  2.0
#3:  apple  1.5
#4: orange  7.0
#5: orange  7.0
#6:  melon 14.0
#7:  melon 15.0
#8:  melon 15.0
#9:  melon 16.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.Does python has similar method?

Comment: @Robin1988 Yes, the code is in R.  I posted it because you tagged with `r`.