# Box-plot in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, boxplot

I have two csv files each of them has one column.
That column has shared information between them like PassengerId,Name,Sex,Age. etc.

I am trying to draw a graph box plot of the ages of the passengers  distribution per title(Mr, Mrs etc.). I get an error. how to pass the error that the plot can be drawn ?

```
import csv as csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
csv_file_object = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'r')) 

header = next(csv_file_object)
data=[] 

for row in csv_file_object:
    data.append(row)
data = np.array(data) 

csv_file_object1 = csv.reader(open('train.csv', 'r')) 
header1 = next(csv_file_object1) 
data1=[] 

for row in csv_file_object:
    data1.append(row)
data1 = np.array(data1)


Mergerd_file = header.merge(header1, on='PassengerId')

df = pd.DataFrame(Mergerd_file, index=['pAge', 'Tilte'])

df.T.boxplot(vert=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25)
plt.show()
```

I get error  this error

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-0d7fafc1fcf9> in <module>()
     21 
     22 
---> 23 Mergerd_file = header.merge(header1, on='PassengerId')
     24 
     25 df = pd.DataFrame(Mergerd_file, index=['pAge', 'Tilte'])

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'merge'
```

Comment: Just for note Python 2 doesn't complain abou tthat, but does complain about "AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'merge'" later on.

Comment: Well this has nothing to do with boxplot in pandas. Btw, if you use pandas, then use directly `pd.read_csv()` to import your dataframe, then `pd.concat` and use `seaborn` to plot the boxplot. If your question is more on how to use the csv library, remove all the unnecessary part, or ask a separate question and make this one clearer

Comment: My aim s to do box plot of the ages of the passengers distribution per title using pandas jrjc

Comment: I am a bit confused - in csv is no column `title`, do you think `Sex` column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) first, then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) both `DataFrames` and last create [`boxplot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html):

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('el/test.csv')
print (df1.head())

df2 = pd.read_csv('el/train.csv')
print (df2.head())

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df['Title'] = df.Name.str.extract(', (.*)\.', expand=False)
print (df.head())

df[['Age','Title']].boxplot(vert=False, by='Title')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25)
plt.show()
```

Comment: There is no separate column for the title. However, under the name there is e.g Braund, Mr. Owen Harris so its the Mr

Comment: Ok, you can try yourself, you can also check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33573408/2901002)

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer :)

Comment: Thank you for accepting. Small advice if you post some question in future  - check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for better questions. Good luck!

Comment: I tried to exclude the other titles than Dr','Mrs','Mr' ,'Sir
using df['Title']= df.Name.str.extract(', (.*)\.', expand=False).isin(['Dr','Mrs','Mr' ,'Sir']) however i get onlt true and flase ?

Comment: Need booelan indexing like `df = df[df.Title.isin(['Dr','Mrs','Mr' ,'Sir'])]` after extracting in new line.

Answer (score 2):

The code you're using is for Python 2, yet you're running Python 3. In Python 3 (and recommended in Python 2.6+), the proper way to advance iterator is to use

```
header = next(csv_file_object1)
```

Furthermore, the file should be opened in text mode `'r'`, not `'rb'`.