# Change Cells in Pandas DataFrame Based on Conditional Slices

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, view, conditional-statements

I'm playing around with the Titanic dataset, and what I'd like to do is fill in all the NaN/Null values of the `Age` column with the median value base on that `Pclass`.

Here is some data:

```
train

PassengerId Pclass  Age
0   1   3   22
1   2   1   35
2   3   3   26
3   4   1   35
4   5   3   35
5   6   1   NaN
6   7   1   54
7   8   3   2
8   9   3   27
9   10  2   14
10  11  1   Nan
```

Here is what I would like to end up with:

```
PassengerId Pclass  Age
0   1   3   22
1   2   1   35
2   3   3   26
3   4   1   35
4   5   3   35
5   6   1   35
6   7   1   54
7   8   3   2
8   9   3   27
9   10  2   14
10  11  1   35
```

The first thing I came up with is this - In the interest of brevity I have only included one slice for `Pclass` equal to 1 rather than including 2 and 3:

```
Pclass_1 = train['Pclass']==1

train[Pclass_1]['Age'].fillna(train[train['Pclass']==1]['Age'].median(), inplace=True)
```

As far as I understand, this method creates a view rather than editing `train` itself (I don't quite understand how this is different from a copy, or if they are analogous in terms of memory -- that is an aside I would love to hear about if possible). I particularly like this Q/A on the topic [View vs Copy, How Do I Tell?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/27367442/pandas-dataframe-view-vs-copy-how-do-i-tell) but it doesn't include the insight I'm looking for.

Looking through Pandas docs I learned why you want to use `.loc` to avoid this pitfall. However I just can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
Pclass_1 = train.loc[:,['Pclass']==1]

Pclass_1.Age.fillna(train[train['Pclass']==1]['Age'].median(),inplace=True)
```

I'm getting lost in indices. This one ends up looking for a column named `False` which obviously doesn't exist. I don't know how to do this without chained indexing. `train.loc[:,train['Pclass']==1]` returns an exception `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided`.

Comment: In general these sort of questions will be answered more rapidly and in greater quantity if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, especially cut and paste able example and expected data.

Comment: I have now added some sample data from the real dataframe.

Comment: @prdctofchem I've updated my answer based on the added sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part of the line,

```
train.loc[:,['Pclass']==1]
```

the part `['Pclass'] == 1` is comparing the list `['Pclass']` to the value `1`, which returns `False`. The `.loc[]` is then evaluated as `.loc[:,False]` which is causing the error.

I think you mean:

```
train.loc[train['Pclass']==1]
```

which selects all of the rows where Pclass is 1. This fixes the error, but it will still give you the "SettingWithCopyWarning".

**EDIT 1**

(old code removed)

Here is an approach that uses `groupby` with `transform` to create a `Series`
containing the median `Age` for each `Pclass`. The `Series` is then used as the argument to `fillna()` to replace the missing values with the median. Using this approach will correct all passenger classes at the same time, which is what the OP originally requested. The solution comes from the answer to [Python-pandas Replace NA with the median or mean of a group in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573408/python-pandas-replace-na-with-the-median-or-mean-of-a-group-in-dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

tbl = """PassengerId Pclass  Age
0   1   3   22
1   2   1   35
2   3   3   26
3   4   1   35
4   5   3   35
5   6   1
6   7   1   54
7   8   3   2
8   9   3   27
9   10  2   14
10  11  1
"""

train = pd.read_table(StringIO(tbl), sep='\s+')
print('Original:\n', train)
median_age = train.groupby('Pclass')['Age'].transform('median') #median Ages for all groups
train['Age'].fillna(median_age, inplace=True)
print('\nNaNs replaced with median:\n', train)
```

The code produces:

```
 Original:
     PassengerId  Pclass   Age
0             1       3  22.0
1             2       1  35.0
2             3       3  26.0
3             4       1  35.0
4             5       3  35.0
5             6       1   NaN
6             7       1  54.0
7             8       3   2.0
8             9       3  27.0
9            10       2  14.0
10           11       1   NaN

NaNs replaced with median:
     PassengerId  Pclass   Age
0             1       3  22.0
1             2       1  35.0
2             3       3  26.0
3             4       1  35.0
4             5       3  35.0
5             6       1  35.0
6             7       1  54.0
7             8       3   2.0
8             9       3  27.0
9            10       2  14.0
10           11       1  35.0
```

One thing to note is that this line, which uses `inplace=True`:

```
train['Age'].fillna(median_age, inplace=True)
```

can be replaced with assignment using `.loc`:

```
train.loc[:,'Age'] = train['Age'].fillna(median_age)
```

Comment: If I apply this to a dataset with NaN values in more than one Pclass, will it fill them in the right places because I have a GroupBy df? Or do I still need to specify to match up Pclass values before doing so? I'm also wondering if simply using the aggregate method `.median()` instead of `.transform('median')` is a better choice in my case.

Comment: @prdctofchem The `groupby` will work correctly for NaNs in more than 1 Pclass. I just did a test and the `transform()` _is required_ for this to work. You should test the code both ways to see why the `transform()` is important. If you've found this answer helpful, please upvote it and accept the answer by clicking on the gray checkmark.

Comment: Additional information on `transform()`: [Understanding the Transform Function in Pandas](http://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html)